# Not getting quick docs alongside suggestions in Vs Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea

[image: Flutter Quick Docs]

In the picture above, the ide is giving quick docs for lowest as seen on the left when lowest is highlighted. The picture is from Android Studio and Im using Vs code. I used to get these as well and they were helpful since im a beginner but im not getting these anymore. Ive tried flutter clean and other stuff but it doesnt fix :(

Comment: Is there no one who can help me?? :((

Comment: Is there an `i` button you can click on to expand the docs? Like in this gif https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/editor/intellisense/intellisense_docs.gif

Comment: It wasnt an ```i``` button but it was ```>``` instead and it worked!! Thank you sir I've been finding a solution for weeks now xd.